# How to fix stripped tire valve stem?

Tags: tires

My tire's valve stem is stripped (both top and middle section) that I cannot even put a cap on. Is there a way to fix the thread without replacing the whole thing?

[image: Stripped Valve Stem]

Answer (score 1):

To me it looks more like it's not round anymore (taken a beating). In your case I don't think there's much of an option besides getting a new one installed. You could *try* to put a die on it of the right size and get the threads worked out ... you'd be in no worse shape.

As an aside, while not optimal, if you're not leaking air, you don't really need to worry about it too much. If it isn't, I'd suggest getting it replaced at the next tire change.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a flexible vinyl cap, like an automotive vacuum cap . Or the hardware store sells vinyl caps to cover exposed threads on gate hardware, etc.